# unable to get admin page for my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, docker, networking, centos, webserver

Please help me out with this problem which making me sick.

Aim : 
    i was about to to setup a website in GCE instance (GoogleCloud Platfrom)
Setup : 
       Centos 7 instance lets call it as "host-vm"  , 
docker engine installed in it , were wordpress and mariadb runs as a container , were the host-vm port *80* is mapped with container port *80*  ; 
port 80 is allowed as TCP as service and Firewall rule in VPC is allowed for port 80  ; my host-vm ephemeral IP (which is dynamic)

[image]

issue :
    initially it was working (am able to get the admin page and my webpages got loaded ) on the first day.

on followed by next day ! External IP got changed , because it is ephemeral.
 when i try to access my website using the URL " : 80"
[image]

When i try to curl my external IP
[[image]][

When i see the WordPress log :
    $docker container logs -f wordpress

[image]
 I don't have idea what this logs means but :-( , but one thing "http://35.228.247.218/wp-admin/options-reading.php" this does not contains my  current external IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reserved a static external IP to the host-vm. And my issue got resolved.